# Extendability of a continuous function on Comb Space

Tags: algebraic-topology, continuity

I have been asked to prove the following -

$C$ be the comb space in the Euclidean Space $R^2$.

$A =$ { $(a,0) : a=0 \ or \  a= \frac 1n, for \ some \ n \in N$}. Define $f:A \to C$ by $f(a,0)=(a,1)$. Then $f$ has no continuous extension over $C$.

I have no clue how to approach the problem. The facts that I know about comb space is that - comb space is contractible. But it is not contractible respect to the point $(1,0)$. But I don't think these facts will be helpful for the problem. Please provide some hints on how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $g:C\to C$ is a continuous functionn such that $g\upharpoonright A=f$. Show that for each $n\in\Bbb N$ and each $y\in(0,1)$ there must be an $x_{n,y}\in\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)$ such that

$$g(x_{n,y},0)=\left\langle\frac1n,y\right\rangle\,.$$

Use the fact that $\left[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]\times\{0\}$ is connected.

Conclude that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}g(x_{n,y},0)=\langle0,y\rangle$ for each $y\in(0,1)$. On the other hand, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle x_{n,y},0\rangle=\langle 0,0\rangle$ for each $y\in(0,1)$, so ... ?